# Change value by JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function, button

The value of the button should change in 1 or 0, but the echo $_POST["ordina"] give always 1 and I don't understand because the code seems correct.

```
<script> function order() {
if (document.ordination.ordina.value == "1") { 
    document.ordination.ordina.value = "0";
} else { 
    document.ordination.ordina.value = "1"; 
} }</script>

<?php echo $_POST["ordina"]; ?>

<form id="ordination" name="ordination" method="POST" action="">
<button type="submit" value="1" class="button" name="ordina" onclick="order();return true;">Ordina</button>
```

The alert(document.ordination.ordina.value) give always 1.

Some can help me?

Comment: [It's actually changing in my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gsyxc/)

Comment: `alert(document.ordination.ordina.value)` first to see if you are accessing the right thing :)

Comment: @David Just for a bit of fun, [the same code shortened](http://jsfiddle.net/Gsyxc/1/)

Comment: Every time you submit the form, the page is loading, so the if condition will never be true and the value will always be set to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it now..

```
<script> function order() {
if (document.ordination.ordina.value == "1") {
     alert(document.ordination.ordina.value);  // this one shows 1
    document.ordination.ordina.value = "0";
} else { 
    alert(document.ordination.ordina.value);  // this one shows 0
    document.ordination.ordina.value = "1"; 
} }</script>

<?php echo $_POST['ordina'];?>

<form id="ordination" name="ordination" method="POST" action="">
<button type="submit" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ordina'])){echo $_POST['ordina'];}else{ echo '1';}?>" class="button" name="ordina" id="ordina" onclick="order();return true;">Ordina</button>
```

after you submit this form the `<?php echo $_POST['ordina'];?>`  is 0...
and set to button value as 0 and again submit the value can be changed to 1.

and its consequently changed 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 but you have first time load this page means the alert shows 1 only..

Comment: How does this answer the question? Or even solve the problem?

Comment: They need only the alert=>alert(document.ordination.ordina.value) . **first alert shows '1' and second alert shows '0' because the value changed by the script document.ordination.ordina.value = "0";**. and submitting the value returned by the echo $_POST['ordina'] is 0 only.. pls check this in your environment..

Comment: now i have edited by the value in button element => **value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ordina'])){echo $_POST['ordina'];}else{ echo '1';}?>"**

Answer (score 1):

This always return 1, because your button is a "submit" button, so the body is reloaded each time you click on the button.

```
    <script>
    function order() {
    if (document.ordination.ordina.value == "1") { 
        document.ordination.ordina.value = "0";
    } else { 
        document.ordination.ordina.value = "1"; 
    }
    alert(document.ordination.ordina.value);
    }
    </script>

    <form id="ordination" name="ordination" method="POST" action="">
    <button type="button" value="1" class="button" name="ordina" id="ordina" onclick="order();return true;">Ordina</button>

    </form>
```

I change type "submit" for "button", then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> function order() {
if ($("#ordina").val() == "1") { 
    $("#ordina").val(0);
} else { 
    $("#ordina").val(1); 
} }</script>

<?php echo $_POST["ordina"]; ?>

<form id="ordination" name="ordination" method="POST" action="">
<button type="submit" value="1" class="button" name="ordina" id="ordina" onclick="order();return true;">Ordina</button>
```

Comment: What is `va` supposed to be?

Comment: $("#ordina").va() its not a correct stmt ..  **$("#ordina").val() is the right one.**